# pass error to admin_notices on "quick edit"/save_post action

Tags: save-post, quick-edit

I currently have `add_action('admin_notices','my_notice_function');` updating correctly whenever a page is refreshed (it's checking if a certain page has a certain parent) but when using the "Quick Edit" my admin_notices is not fired.

When trying to hook the same function into `add_action('save_post','my_notice_function'));` it breaks the formatted table and doesn't display the error message in the normal `admin_notices` section at the top of the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code, as it stands:

```
public function init() {
  add_action('admin_notices','page_check');
  add_action('save_post','page_check');
}

public function page_check(){

  if(PluginCommon::verifyPages('error')){
    ?>
    <div class='alert-message alert-danger' id='page_errors'>
      <h2>A problem has been detected.</h2>
      <ul><?php echo PluginCommon::verifyPages('error'); ?></ul>
    </div>
    <?php 
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code you are using and clarify what you are trying to achieve? Are you expecting the admin notice to update when you update a post with quick edit?

Comment: added code. yes, expecting admin notice to show/update when updating a post with quick edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `admin_notices` hook fires only once per page load, and isn't fired when a post is quick-edited.

You would have to do it browser-side with javascript - that is, listen for when someone edits and saves a post (which is done via AJAX) and use javascript to display a message.

A quick glance at the javascript file responsible for quick editing ([wp-admin/js/inline-edit-post.dev.js](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/js/inline-edit-post.dev.js)), and unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a way of knowing when the AJAX response has been received.